# Where is contacts page in magento

Tags: magento

Where is `contacts` **(ie Contact Us page)** in magento?

please anybody help me to find out `contacts page` and the `xml which calling cntacts`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contact page xml location (copy to your local layout folder) /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/contacts.xml

```
<reference name="content">
     <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\contacts` page in the default Magento theme is generated from `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\contacts\form.phtml`. But if you have a different theme installed then there should be a corresponding form.phtml file in there.

A useful trick if you are wondering where a Magento page is coming from is to switch on "Template Path Hints". In Magento admin go to System->Configuration->Developer, change the "Current Configuration Scope:" (top-left dropdown) to the relevant website (probably "Main Website"), and under "Debug" settings set "Template Path Hints" to Yes and save the config.

Then whatever page you visit in the frontend will show which template files have been used to generate the parts of the page.

Comment: This was a huge help into locating where the file was for the block. Thank you so much!